# VBA wait for everything in a webpage to completely load

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, extract

I'm trying to pull some information from a website after navigating to it but I can't seem to wait until it completely loads. I've been trying to loop until the class at (0) contains text. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

Dim elements2 As IHTMLElementCollection

    IE.Navigate "https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/955559644646354/"
        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
Dim x
x = 0
Do Until x = 1
Set elements2 = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("_3cgd")

If WorksheetFunction.IsText(elements2(0).innerText) = True Then
    MsgBox ((elements2(0).innerText))
    x = 1
  Else
  Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
  End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't actually see that class on the page. I am guessing it may be a region thing. Can you also indicate what the actual info is you want off the page? (I see an ad for Brand New Neon Blue & Red Nintendo Switch with Warranty). You have nice answers already but I would still be interested in seeing any other ways to attack this.

Comment: Yeah I can't load that particular link anymore so the item might have been delisted. The information I was looking to get is the seller's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (untested)

```
Dim t, elements2, txt

t = Timer
txt = ""

Do 
    Set elements2 = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("_3cgd")
    If elements2.length > 0 Then
        txt = elements2(0).innerText
        If Len(txt) > 0 Then Exit Do
    End If

    If (Timer - t) > 10 Then Exit Do 'exit if too long waiting

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add lines below to wait for loading the web page completely.

```
' Wait while IE loading...
'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
```

Below is the full working example:

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://www.automateexcel.com/excel/"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

    'Unload IE
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Further, You can try to modify this code example as per your requirement.

Reference:

(1) [Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)